# Cargo Build Error - File Missing

Tags: rust

Trying to compile the example given at https://github.com/gifnksm/twitter-api-rs on a 32bit Windows 10 machine, I get the following error - any ideas as to what to do?

(I had a previous issue with the curl-sys compilation, which required the environment variable CFLAGS setting to '-mmmx -msse' )

```
D:\Proj\Rust\projects\twittest>cargo build --verbose
       Fresh rustc-serialize v0.3.16
       Fresh pkg-config v0.3.5
       Fresh libc v0.1.10
       Fresh winapi v0.2.2
       Fresh winapi-build v0.1.1
       Fresh matches v0.1.2
       Fresh log v0.3.2
       Fresh url v0.2.37
       Fresh advapi32-sys v0.1.2
       Fresh kernel32-sys v0.1.4
       Fresh rand v0.3.11
       Fresh gcc v0.3.13
       Fresh time v0.1.32
   Compiling curl-sys v0.1.25
     Running `D:\Proj\Rust\projects\twittest\target\debug\build\curl-sys-865cd014190c57f1\build-script-build`
       Fresh libz-sys v0.1.8
       Fresh rust-crypto v0.2.31
failed to run custom build command for `curl-sys v0.1.25`
Process didn't exit successfully: `D:\Proj\Rust\projects\twittest\target\debug\build\curl-sys-865cd014190c57f1\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stdout
cargo:rustc-link-search=D:\Proj\Rust\projects\twittest\target\debug\build\curl-sys-865cd014190c57f1\out/lib
cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=curl
cargo:root=D:\Proj\Rust\projects\twittest\target\debug\build\curl-sys-865cd014190c57f1\out
cargo:include=D:\Proj\Rust\projects\twittest\target\debug\build\curl-sys-865cd014190c57f1\out/include
cargo:rustc-flags=-l ws2_32
curlsys running: "sh" "-c" "/c/Users/Me/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-121aea75f9ef2ce2/curl-sys-0.1.25/curl/configure --with-winssl --enable-static=yes --enable-shared=no --enable-optimize --prefix=D:/Proj/Rust/projects/twittest/target/debug/build/curl-sys-865cd014190c57f1/out --without-librtmp --without-libidn --without-libssh2 --without-nghttp2 --disable-ldap --disable-ldaps --disable-ftp --disable-rtsp --disable-dict --disable-telnet --disable-tftp --disable-pop3 --disable-imap --disable-smtp --disable-gopher --disable-manual"

--- stderr
thread '<main>' panicked at 'cmd.status() return the error The system cannot find the file specified.
 (os error 2)', C:\Users\Me\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-121aea75f9ef2ce2\curl-sys-0.1.25\build.rs:134
```

I am using http://mingw-w64.org but I suspect the problem lies with the 32bit build parameters in the library configure sh files (possibly!)

Comment: Same issue here I think: https://github.com/carllerche/curl-rust/issues/71

Comment: Please do not include greetings/parting words on SO, and don't worry, as strange as it sounds, the Rust community appears to be populated by human beings.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu, noted!

Comment: Your rust projects seems to be on `D:`, but the failing commands looks at `/c/Users/Me/`.  Is your home directory actually `C:\Users\Me`, and is there a .cargo registry there?

Comment: Exactly that, my project dir is on D: , with the cargo depositories under the system user home path. Surely any scripts in the build process should know this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `--prefix=D:/Proj/...` part is wrong, and should be `--prefix=/d/Proj/...`.

In https://github.com/carllerche/curl-rust/blob/master/curl-sys/build.rs#L110 , there is a hardcoded `replace("C:\\", "/c/")` but no handling of other unit labels.

In other words, it seems curl-rust currently does not support building when your project root is not on `C:`.  Would it be possible to move your projects directory, or at least the code for this project?

Comment: I moved the project to C: , with the same problem - however my Rust installation is on D: , I will have to remove and reinstall to C: - I'll give this a try when time allows.

Comment: Of course, if this is the source of the problem, it should be considered a bug in curl-rust and fixed there.

Comment: Indeed.. I have neither MSYS2, mingw or Rust installed to the default locations, so anything with an absolute path will fail. I'll have a play with setting symlinks (or reinstalling to the default loc) to see if that fixes it when I get a chance.

Comment: You could try patching your copy of curl-rust ... Everywhere it does something with `C:`, just do the same for all volumes you have ...  I hope it works and I hope they will accept a pull request for it!  :-)